# creating a class within another class memory allocation

Tags: c++, class, memory, dynamic, heap-memory

If I have a few classes, say one is a base class and it is created inside another class, will it be located on the stack or heap if the "outside" class is created with the new operator but the class created inside of it isn't. For example:

```
class baseclass
{
   //code here
};

class outside
{
     baseclass mybase;
     //more code
};

int main()
{
    outside *myclass;
    myclass = new outside;
}
```

Is mybase allocated on the heap as well?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. That's correct. It does not require an additional new or delete for it though.

Answer (score 1):

Your `outside` and `baseclass` are created at the same memory area.